# The account running the TFS build service (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) needs to be added as a system user in the Release Management Server

Tags: tfs, build-process, release-management, ms-release-management

I am receiving the above error when attempting to trigger a release from my build. The build works on its own, and the release works on its own, but I cannot trigger the release.

My problem is that there is no such thing as a system user in Release Management. There is a Service User, and the above user is set as a Service User. It's also set as a Release Manager.

It is also in the Project Collection Administrators group in TFS and has the "Make requests on behalf of others" permission. I've done everything I think I need to do in order to get this to work.

The only thing I can think of is that Release Management is installed on a different server to TFS (although it is on the same server as the build agent), and perhaps it is using a "different" NETWORK SERVICE user, since I believe the NETWORK SERVICE user is local (although I'm not sure).

I've tried everything I can find. Other people are receiving this error, but it always seems to be resolved by setting the Service User permission in Release Management.

Is there anything else I need to set up to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about the Network Service account being local to each machine.  And that appears to be your issue.  When a process running as a local [NetworkService tries to authenticate with a remote system, it does so as domain\machinename$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806438/login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename).

So to fix your issue, try to add your TFS build service computer name in the appropriate local security groups of your release management server by using `domain\{YOURTFSMACHINENAME}$` as the account for your TFS build service.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't appear to help. I've confirmed that the build agent performing the build, however, *is* running on the same server as Release Management, so it looks like something else is going on.

Comment: Is your build controller on the same server as your release management?  If not you might want to try adding that servername. There is also [this post (Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901507/error-the-account-running-the-tfs-build-service-tfsbuildservices-needs-to?rq=1) about disabling the proxy on the build server to resolve the same error.

Comment: My build controller is not on the same server as release management, but my build agent is. And yes, I saw that post - it says, "After disabling the Proxy in Build server for account tfsbuildservices, it’s started working as expected". In my case, the account is NETWORK SERVICE (not tfsbuildservices), but I don't know what this means. What does it mean to "disable the Proxy in the Build server for an account?" What proxy?

Comment: RESOLVED: Marked @malexander's answer as correct, since this was definitely part of the problem (although domain\{machinename}? didn't work, but {machinename}? on its own did). But there was another problem in the configuration of the Build Service itself, where the connection to TFS was configured as http://machinename:8080/[...] and not http://machinename.domain:8080/[...].  Although TFS seemed to function fine like this, ReleaseManagementBuild.exe (which is what actually triggers the release) did not, and produced the above error, which was not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The best option when you are using a distributed installation is to use explicit domain service accounts. While you can make network service work it is far easier to use an account.

I would recommend that you create a domain\tfsrm account and use that for communication.

Comment: +1 for comment. I think this is what I'll do if I have any more problems. For now, I'm just going to back slowly away...

Answer (score 0):

I've received the very same error, but in my case the culprit was that the RM client must not only be installed on TFS-RM server, but also **minimally configured** with the RM server address.
Otherwise, on a single-server deployment, using Network Service as TFS and build agent service accounts works just fine.